# How to insert a link in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product

I'm very new to Magento. I have created a page, and I want to insert a link.

I have this page: 
[image]

When clicking on "*Order Detail*", It's will move to another page. I tried to research but I can't find a solution. 
**Can anyone help??? Thanks**

Comment: If you have any confusion, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect on custom module page. Then, you should create this files :

> Create front router file : **app/code/Vendor/Helloworld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Vendor_Helloworld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Create new controller : **app/code/Vendor/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
    * Default customer account page
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Welcome to RH Helloworld module'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
?>
```

> Create Block file : **Vendor\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Block;
class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getHelloworldData()
    {
        return 'Helloworld block file call successfully';
    }
}
?>
```

> Create layout file : **Vendor/Helloworld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" name="formbuilder" template="Vendor_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Create template file : **Vendor/Helloworld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml**

```
<h3>
<?php echo $block->getHelloworldData(); ?>
</h3>
```

=====================================================================

Now, add link in your phtml like :

```
<a href="<?pgp echo $this->getUrl("helloworld/index/index"); ?>">Order Detail</a>
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use product getProductUrl() function like.

```
<a href="<?pgp echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">Order Detail</a>
```

Comment: Hi @Shorabh. I'm trying to do like this:<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                    <a href="<?= $block->getDetailUrl($item) ?>" class="action view">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Detail')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
Could you explain more detail about your answered? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add link with this reference :-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseURL = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

$baseURL is your site URL and you can append page name as required

<a href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>YourPageName">Order Detail</a>
```

Comment: Don't use object manager direct. It's bad practise.